# Why is dot product commutative but matrix multiplication is not?

Tags: matrices, vectors

I have been told $a \cdot b = a^Tb$

If dot product is commutative, then $a \cdot b = a^Tb = b \cdot a = b^Ta$

So we get $a^Tb = b^Ta$. A contradiction to matrix multiplication not
being commutative.

Comment: There are no matrix products here for which you can even interchange the order, unless everything is in dimension $1$ (where the multiplication is indeed commutative).

Comment: The dot-product is only for vectors in the way you're talking about it here.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook  So you're saying $a \cdot b = a^Tb$ is not true for nxm matrices and only for nx1 vectors?

Comment: $a^T\ne a$ and $b^T\ne b$, so how is the identity that you’ve got here an example of commutativity? The identity works because a scalar is its own transpose.

Comment: @A_for_Abacus correct. If you want to talk about a dot-product for matrices then the natural choice is $\langle A, B \rangle = \text{trace}(A^TB)$ which is actually just what you'd think; $\langle A, B \rangle = A_{11}B_{11}+A_{12}B_{12}+\cdots + A_{nn}B_{nn}$. It is the dot-product for the matrices strung out as $n^2$-vectors. However, I would refer to it as an "inner product" since I reserve the phrase dot-product for the context of column or row vectors over a field.

Comment: I generally protest when some asks why something is not true. My answer usually is, *In mathematics, Nothing Is True. Unless there’s a proof that it’s true.* Perhaps your question is not quite appropriate to that answer, but still: If a certain kind of combination is commutative, you should be aware of (or know) the proof. If another kind is not commutative, you should furnish a counterexample, and see why that is not apposite to the first situation. After all, mathematics is not a matter of rules, but of understandings and explanations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is not commutative *in general*. In Mathematics, "in general it is not..." means: "there are cases in which it is not..."; it *does not* mean "in all cases it is not...".
Sure, there are pair of matrices whose product is the same whatever is the order in the product.

However, your case is different: you are *not* providing an example of two matrices whose product commutes. The product does not commute in your example:
$$
[a_1,\ldots,a_n]
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\
\vdots\\
b_n
\end{bmatrix}= a_1b_1+\ldots+a_nb_n\in \mathbb R
$$
while
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\
\vdots\\
b_n
\end{bmatrix} [a_1,\ldots,a_n]= 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 a_1 &\ldots &b_1 a_n\\
\vdots & & \vdots \\
b_n a_1& \ldots & b_n a_n
\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}
$$
Commutativity is out of question for pair of matrices which are not square matrices (of the same order). For square matrices of the same order, commutativity occurs in particular cases.

Comment: So are there restrictions for the dot product because in my above equations, it seems you can plug ANY matrix into $a \cdot b$. Thus, making rest of the proof true.

Comment: $a,b$ have to be vectors in $a \cdot b$. In particular, $a$ is $ n \times 1$ and $b$ is $n \times 1$ so $a \cdot b = a^Tb$ is a $(1 \times n)(n \times 1) = 1 \times 1$ product.

Comment: I expanded the answer to reply to your question

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph, which is the real answer to the question. I might add that $b^Ta=(a^Tb)^T$, which is then equal to $a^Tb$ because a scalar is its own transpose.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you can't multiply two vectors when they are regarded as matrices.  Hence the "$\cdot$" in $a\cdot b$ doesn't refer to the product of two matrices.

But for any two matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same dimension you may define
$$A\ast B=\operatorname{trace}(A^TB).$$
For this product we have that $A\ast B=B\ast A$.

Comment: So dot product only works for vectors (not matrices), and they have to be in the same dimension?

Comment: The same dimension is always required. One may define an inner product $\ast$ for matrices in the way I defined.  And the (usual) dot product of vectors is then a special case for matrices  of dimension $n\times 1$, that is, vectors of dimension $n$.